# Let $G$ be a group and $a,b∈G$. Suppose order of $(ab)$ in $G$ is $n$. Show that $(ba)^n=e$ Prove that the order of $(ba)$ in $G$ is $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am confused since the definition of order says that $(ab)^n=e$, therefore does just showing that ab=ba solves both parts or is it two different solutions?

Assume $(ab)^n=e$, following the definition of order since n is a finite number.

$(ab)^n=\underbrace{(ab)(ab)(ab)\cdots(ab)}_{n~\text{copies}}$

$=a\underbrace{(ba)(ba)(ba)\cdots(ba)}_{n-1~\text{copies}}b$

$=a(ba)^{n-1} b$

From this, we get that $(ba)^{n-1}=a^{-1} b^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}$, therefore we have $(ba)^n=e$. Also proving that $ab=ba$.

Would this answer both of the questions above since then it show that both $ba^n=e$ and that the order of $ba$ would be $n$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $ab=ba$ does not always hold unless $G$ is Abelian

Comment: "*showing that $ab=ba$*"  But... no one said that the group was abelian.  You can't show that $ab=ba$ because that could very well be false.

Comment: Would I be able to prove that ab=ba with the information I am given?

Comment: proving $ab=ba$ seems too tough or rather impossible with the given info, try to write $(ab)^n= (ab)(ab)...(ab)=a(ba)(ba)...(ba)b$

Comment: This is what I have came up with so far::

Assume (ab)^n=e, following the definition of order since n is a finite number.
(ab)^n=(ab)(ab)(ab)………(ab)^(n-1) (ab)^n
=a(ba)(ba)(ba)……(ba)b
=a(ba)^(n-1) b

Comment: Maybe try entering that into your post rather than the comments.  The formatting makes it very difficult to read.  While you're at it, you might have a look at this [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make it even easier to read by properly formatting your equations with MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: You concluded at the end "*also proving $ab=ba$*"  This cannot be correct, because as mentioned, there exist non-abelian groups.  What makes you believe that $ab=ba$ from what you have written?  Because we need to correct this grave misconception before it causes more trouble down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You have $e = (ab)^n=a(ba)^{n-1}b$. From this you can multiply $a^{-1}$ from the left and $b^{-1}$ from the right to get $a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ba)^{n-1}\implies (ba)^{-1}=(ba)^{n-1}$ which gives you $(ba)^{n}=e$. From this you can conclude what the question is asking.

Comment: This shows the order of $ba$ divides $n$.  Now suppose the order of $ba$ is  $k\lt n$.  Then $(ab)^k=e$, by interchanging $a$ and $b$, a contradiction.